# Ubuntu scp to external hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, backup, external, media, scp

I have an external hard drive, called MyDisk - I also run a command to scp a folder from another server to my external hard drive. The problem is - my scp downloads the backups to a folder /media/MyDisk but this takes up the hard disk space on the main hard drive.

I need to be able to write these straight to the hard drive without download to /media/MyDisk (as this is essentially like downloading the files to /home/myuser or another local folder)

When I look directly on MyDisk I see my backups, but even when I eject the drive and look in /media/MyDisk - the backups are there.

Is it possible to just download them directly to MyDisk without involving /media/ folder? I notice that when you want to change directory in the terminal you go through cd /media/MyDisk but is there a way to avoid using this "local" folder?

Really confused, any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you have performed the scp both with the external drive mounted and without the external drive mounted? With the external drive mounted the scp would write to /media/MyDisk with the external drive mounted at this point. If then the external drive was removed and the scp was run again the files would be written to /media/MyDisk as part of the root file system.

Comment: Thanks very much - this must have happened as since I deleted the contents of /media/myDisk and then set backups to run again - it has not interfered with my normal disk drive.